# Merge Two Arrays into One in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular6

I want to merge two arrays into one in TypeScript.

First Array Object:

```
export interface Item{
    Label : string,
    Code : string,
    Price : number,
}
```

Second Array Object:

```
export interface Amount
{
     Code :  string,
     Amount: number
}
```

Result Array Object:

```
export interface CombinedList{
    Code : string,
    ItemAmount : number,
    ItemPrice : number
}
```

In result array i want to merge Item array and Amount array by Code. (In Item and Amount is 3 elements with this same Code).

Example:

```
ItemsArray : Item[] = 
[{ Label : "One", Code : "ONE", Price : 5,86}, 
{Label : "Two", Code : "TWO", Price : 9,99}, 
{Label : "Three", Code : "THR", Price : 752}]

AmountsArray : Amount[] = 
[{ Code : "ONE", Amount : 120}, 
{Code :"TWO", Amount : 250}, 
{Code :"THR", Amount : 165}]
```

And result:

```
CombinedArray : CombinedList[] = 
[{Code : "ONE", ItemAmount : 120, ItemPrice: 5,86 }, 
{Code :"TWO", ItemAmount : 250, ItemPrice: 9,99}, 
{Code :"THR", ItemAmount : 165, ItemPrice: 752}]
```

Comment: So you basically want a join? Is the relation one to one? Or? Each item in ItemsArray has an exact corresponding item in AmountsArray?

Comment: One to one relation. I Have to combine them and compare by Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I would do it:

First reduce the amounts to a key/value pair, where the key is the code and the value is the amount. This way you can quickly find amounts by code:

```
const amountsByCode = AmountsArray.reduce((byCode, amount) => { byCode[amount.Code] = amount; return byCode; }, {} as { [key: string]: Amount });
```

2nd step is to map the items and add the missing fields:

```
const CombinedArray = ItemsArray.map(item => ({ Code: item.Code, ItemAmount: amountsByCode[item.Code].Amount, ItemPrice: item.Price }));
```

If the arrays are always ordered (code to code), you can directly zip them:

```
const CombinedArray = ItemsArray.map((item, index) => ({ Code: item.Code, ItemAmount: amounts[index].Amount, ItemPrice: item.Price }));
```

Comment: @voltdev In that case it's safe to assume that item x in both arrays will have the same `Code` so you can just map directly.