# How to merge an object to an object array in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, lodash

Merge two objects in typescript.

```
const data = {
"date": "12",
"time": "1.30pm",
"name": "Arun"
};

const newData = {
"date": ["9/12/2023"],
"name": ["Vijay"]
};

const result = _.merge(data, newData);
console.log(result);

//The Result I'm getting is 
{
  date: ["9/12/2023"],
  name: ["Vijay"],
  time: "1.30pm"
}.

//But the expected result is:

{
date: "9/12/2023",
  name: "Vijay",
  time: "1.30pm
}
```

Please note that the fields in the **newData** object may change. I Used _.merge() function from lodash but it merges along with the string value inside the array. I need to merge only the value present inside the array to the **data** object

Comment: why have the values inside an array in new data

Comment: if thats not in your control use mergeWith and return the first element of array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge Two Arrays into One in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52055384/merge-two-arrays-into-one-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.assign` is used to merge two object.
But this case, value need to changed.
Simply use for-in loop.

```js
const data = {
    date: "12",
    time: "1.30pm",
    name: "Arun",
};

const newData = {
    date: ["9/12/2023"],
    name: ["Vijay"],
};

for (const key in newData) {
    data[key] = newData[key][0];
  //data[key] = String(newData[key]);
}

console.log(data);
```